# Best options to replace my Xfinity cable modem? (and avoid the $11/mo charge)

Tags: cable

I am cutting the cable. Actually I just called Comcast. Cancelled my voice and TV. I will get Extreme Internet (250mbps) plus the modem rental from them.

Is there a list of good options to buy my own cable modem and stop paying Comcast for renting it? Am I loosing any feature/convenience/putting myself at risk by buying my own instead of renting it from Comcast?

Comment: Xfinity has a [tool](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/list-of-approved-cable-modems) that you can use to see if a modem is compatible with your plan. Personally, I would find a modem that is supported at a higher speed than your current plan. You don't want to upgrade speeds in the future to only be held back by the modem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [xFinity](https://mydeviceinfo.xfinity.com/) retail device finder. I use the Motorola that is listed and it is great. Bought it at Best Buy and I do not pay any rental fee. I pay for the 200 Mbps service but get close to 250 Mbps most of the time.